# Sample database for PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, sample-data

I am looking for a sample database (schema+data) for PostgreSQL 9. Is there a repository somewhere for sample databases?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There's a [PgFoundry project](https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/projects/pgFoundry/) that contains several example PostgreSQL databases. Most of these haven't been updated for a while, but will still work with recent PostgreSQL versions.

If you need a bigger database, the [MusicBrainz music metadata database](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/Database_Download) has full database dumps available for download.

Comment: If you need a huge database, you can download tools to bulk generate data for the TPC-H benchmark from http://www.tpc.org/tpch/

Comment: Great on Musicbrainz! I was searching pg data for testing some BI tools, I like this one!

Answer (score 14):

I just published a PostgreSQL port of the Open Source Shakespeare database: https://github.com/catherinedevlin/opensourceshakespeare.  It's much more fun than all those other sample databases.

Comment: why don't you wrap it into dockerfile so can be used as a service using single command?

Comment: License prohibits use in commercial software (e.g. for a test database)

Answer (score 10):

You can find some in the PostgreSQL wiki: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Sample_Databases

Comment: the sample download file no longer exist

Answer (score 2):

Many of the examples referenced here or in other places are defunct or require a good number of hoops to jump through to get working (more than I was willing to jump).

I finally discovered that the [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/) SQL client has a "[Generate Mock Data](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/wiki/Mock-Data-Generation-in-DBeaver)" tool that can fill in tables with sample data.  It can handle various data types, you can give it strings to use for text, and it handles foreign keys. You can configure large numbers of rows (e.g. 900,000) for insert, and it is also DB agnostic so it should work for mySQL, SQL Server, etc.

[image: menu item]
[image: sample data config]

Answer (score 1):

I also made a sample PostgreSQL database based on [IMDb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMDb). I also tried to update the sample exercises, so that a beginner can learn from it and practice on it.

Link: [PostgreSQL Sample Database](https://github.com/raosaif/sample_postgresql_database).

Answer (score 0):

I have found:
http://www.postgression.com/

But the dbsamples main page from pgfoundry disappeared... 
I have rediscovered http://pgfoundry.org/frs/?group_id=1000150